# Как сделать защиту от перебора паролей в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, qtimer

Помогите сделать защиту от перебора паролей, в которой если **`3`** раза пароль при авторизации был набран неверно, то система блокируется на **`5 минут`**.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sqlite3


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(598, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 210, 161, 61))
        self.lineEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 598, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


class Ui_LoadingWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, LoadingWindow):
        LoadingWindow.setObjectName("LoadingWindow")
        LoadingWindow.resize(218, 230)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(LoadingWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 160, 110))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.password.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.English, QtCore.QLocale.UnitedStates))
        self.password.setObjectName("password")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.password, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.login = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.login.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.English, QtCore.QLocale.UnitedStates))
        self.login.setObjectName("login")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.login, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.entry = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.entry.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 140, 75, 23))
        self.entry.setObjectName("entry")
        LoadingWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(LoadingWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 218, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        LoadingWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(LoadingWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        LoadingWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(LoadingWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(LoadingWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, LoadingWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        LoadingWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("LoadingWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("LoadingWindow", "Пароль"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("LoadingWindow", "Логин"))
        self.entry.setText(_translate("LoadingWindow", "Войти"))


class LoadingWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_LoadingWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LoadingWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('LoadingWindow')
        self.con = sqlite3.connect("Staff.db")
        self.entry.clicked.connect(self.search)
        self.n = 0

    def search(self):
        if self.n == 3:
            self.n = 0
            self.password.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.NoEcho)
            self.login.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.NoEcho)
        else:
            cur = self.con.cursor()
            user_data = cur.execute("""select user_role from users where id_user = ? and user_password = ?""",
                                    (self.login.text(), self.password.text())).fetchall()
            if user_data:
                self.wT = MainWindow(self, user_data[0][0])
                self.wT.show()
                self.close()
            else:
                valid = QMessageBox.question(self, '',
                                             "Неверный логин или пароль", QMessageBox.Ok)
        self.n += 1


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('User window')
        self.n = args[-1]
        self.con = sqlite3.connect("Staff.db")
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        self.role = cur.execute("""select title from roles where id_role = ?""", (self.n,)).fetchall()
        self.lineEdit.setText(self.role[0][0])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = LoadingWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id_user       INTEGER NOT NULL
                          UNIQUE,
    user_password STRING  NOT NULL,
    user_role     INTEGER NOT NULL
                          REFERENCES roles (id_role) 
);

CREATE TABLE roles (
    id_role INTEGER UNIQUE
                    NOT NULL
                    PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    title   STRING  NOT NULL
);

Данные Users:

Admin   123 1
роз 123 2
рцх 123 3
роп 123 4
тестировщик 123 5
инжинер 123 6
менеджер    123 7
кладовщик   123 8

Данные Roles:

1   Admin
2   Руководитель отдела закупок
3   Руководитель цеха производства
4   Руководитель отдела продаж
5   Тестировщик
6   Инженер
7   Менеджер смены
8   Кладовщик
```

Comment: Опубликуйте модуль, который создаст БД с таблицами и некоторыми данными.

Comment: Я опубликовал весь код

Comment: Могу показать скриншоты из SQLiteStudio

Comment: Мне, чтобы вам помочь, необходимо запустить приложение. В приложении есть запросы, например `self.role = cur.execute("""select title from roles where id_role = ?""", (self.n,)).fetchall()`. БД не с воздуха берется, вы ее как-то создали, создали таблицы, внесли какие-то данные. Опубликуйте модуль, который создаст БД с таблицами и некоторыми данными.

Comment: Надеюсь я вас правильно понял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
...
class LoadingWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_LoadingWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LoadingWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('LoadingWindow')
        self.con = sqlite3.connect("Staff.db")
        self.entry.clicked.connect(self.search)
        self.n = 0
        self.login.setPlaceholderText("Введите ваш логин")        # +
        self.password.setPlaceholderText("Введите ваш пароль")    # +

    def search(self):
        if self.n == 3:        
            self.n = 0
# -           self.password.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.NoEcho)
# -           self.login.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.NoEcho)

### vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv            
            self.login.clear()
            self.password.clear()
            self.login.setPlaceholderText("Блокировка")
            self.password.setPlaceholderText("Блокировка")
            self.login.setEnabled(False)
            self.password.setEnabled(False)
            self.entry.setEnabled(False)
            QMessageBox.question(self, 'Блокировка',"Ваша учетная запись заблокирована!", QMessageBox.Ok)

            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(5*1000, self.blocking)       # разблокируем через 5 секунд
# +            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(5*60*1000, self.blocking) # разблокируем через 5 минут

        elif not self.login.text() or not self.password.text():
            QMessageBox.question(self, 'Не заполнены поля.', "Введите логин и пароль", QMessageBox.Ok)
### ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        else:
            cur = self.con.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT user_role FROM users where id_user = %s and user_password = '%s'"\
                          % (self.login.text(), self.password.text()))
            user_data = cur.fetchall()

            if user_data:
                self.wT = MainWindow(self, user_data[0][0])
                self.wT.show()
                self.close()
            else:
                QMessageBox.question(self, 'Что-то пошло не так.',
                                     "Неверный логин или пароль", QMessageBox.Ok)
        self.n += 1

### vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv            
    def blocking(self):
        self.login.setPlaceholderText("Введите ваш логин")
        self.password.setPlaceholderText("Введите ваш пароль")
        self.login.setEnabled(True)
        self.password.setEnabled(True)
        self.entry.setEnabled(True)
### ^^^^^^^^^^
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]